# Repeatedly getting "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-domain, domain-security

This problem keeps occurring at random on domain network that I have set up..
This problem occurs only is I use windows 7(pro x64) and does not occur for XP(pro x86 and x64).

Rejoining the client on domain controller solves the problem temporarily but reappears again.
And it is quite tedious to rejoin a number of PCs on repeated basis.
Is there any permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the registry values listed on [the Samba Wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7) that need to be changed. On my previous workplace we got the same errors, and IIRC we just applied a registry patch to each computer before joining the domain. The same registry file is linked to from the wiki: [Win7_Samba3DomainMember.reg](https://bugzilla.samba.org/attachment.cgi?id=4988&action=view)

Another possibility is that you are using an outdated Samba server. According to the wiki the error is typical to versions prior to 3.2.12.

For future-proofing, here is the linked-to registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManWorkstation\Parameters]

"DomainCompatibilityMode"=dword:00000001
"DNSNameResolutionRequired"=dword:00000000
```